# MongoSpark returns wrong count

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I am aware of this issue, and I have been using 2.2.1 : [Why Mongo Spark connector returns different and incorrect counts for a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652026/why-mongo-spark-connector-returns-different-and-incorrect-counts-for-a-query)

When I use this code :

```
val profileDs = MongoSpark.load(sparkSession.sparkContext)
val rddCount = profileDs.count()
val dsCount = profileDs.toDS[LightProfile]().count()
```

`rddCount` returns the good value (1.647.864), but dsCount does not (901.028).

LightProfile is a Scala case class. When I delete some fields from the class, the count on dsCount goes up, closer to the real value, until at some point, when I suppress enough fields, it gets the right count.

I tried all the available Partitioners, but none of them could change the results.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this here : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK-173?filter=-2

The answer is that some fields are optional in my datas, but they were not in my case class. So I changed some fields from type T to Option[T], and this made the trick.