# Spark DataFrame filtering gives inconsistent output

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a MongoDB collection with 26,000 records which I am reading into a DataFrame. It has a column, `column_1` with String value `column_1_value` across all the records. I am trying to filter the DataFrame and get the count as follows

```
val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map("collection" -> collectionName,"spark.mongodb.input.readPreference.name" -> "primaryPreferred", "spark.mongodb.input.database" -> dataBaseName, "spark.mongodb.input.uri" -> hostName))
val dataFrame = MongoSpark.load(spark, readConfig)
df.filter(df.col("column_1") === "column_1_value").count()
```

Where `spark` is the instance of `SparkSession`.

The MongoDB record structure looks something like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("SOME_ID"),
    "column_1" : "column_1_value",
    "column_2" : SOME_VALUE,
    "column_3" : SOME_OTHER_VALUE
}
```

There is no nested structure, and all the records have the same set of fields. I am not accessing the DB during any time while Spark is running

As all the records have the same value of `column_1`, I expected to get the DataFrame size itself as the output, but instead I am getting a lower value. Not only that, I am getting different outcomes each time I run the above. The outcome is normally varying between 15,000 and 24,000.

But the same approach seems to work when the collection size is less, around 5,000.

I have tried the following approaches with no success

- Used `equalTo` instead of `===`
- Used `$column_1`
- Used `isin`
- Used `df.where` instead of `df.filter`
- Used `createOrReplaceTempView` and ran SQL query

The only thing that seems to work is either `df.cache()` or `df.persist()`, none of which I think will be good for the overall performance when working with large data.

What can be the possible reason for this behavior and the ways by which this can be resolved?

My Spark version is 2.2.0, MongoDB version is 3.4. I am running Spark in local mode, with 16 GB of RAM and an 8 core processor.

#### Edit 1

Tried changing the Mongo Spark connector partitioning policy as follows, but with no success.

```
val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map("collection" -> collectionName,"spark.mongodb.input.readPreference.name" -> "primaryPreferred", "spark.mongodb.input.database" -> dataBaseName, "spark.mongodb.input.uri" -> hostName, "spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions" -> "MongoPaginateBySizePartitioner"))
val dataFrame = MongoSpark.load(spark, readConfig)
df.count()
df.filter(df.col("column_1") === "column_1_value").count()
```

The first count returns the correct value, even with the default partitioning strategy, which leads me to believe that the Mongo Connector is working fine.

Comment: Please try to push it a bit towards reproducible problem. Right now it is not answerable. How do you load the data? What is the source? Is the source live (modified as you run Spark code)? How is `column_1` derived? And so on...

Comment: @user8371915 Edited as per your suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Mongo Spark connector returns different and incorrect counts for a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46652026/8371915)

Comment: @user8371915 tried your solution, but it did not work. Edited the question with details